# How to loop through list of options inside if statement in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am extracting items from a subdirectory containing a mixture of files that are audio files in different formats and with different suffixes e.g. `_master` or `_128k`.

I have specified higher up in the code a list of permitted extensions (e.g. `.mp3`) so that I extract only files of the right formats for processing.

I also have a list (suffixExcluded) containing filename suffixes (e.g. `_syndication`) I explicitly want to exclude from further processing.

How do I best write the line that effectively does:

```
if fileExtension in filesAllowed and [LIST OF EXCLUDED SUFFIXES] not in fileName:
```

Is there a neat, compact and elegant (pythonic) way of iterating through my list of exclusions within this `if` clause, or do I need to set up a subsidiary loop to test each item?

Comment: What language are you talking about? Python? If so, please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Sorry - very silly of me to overlook pointing out that I was talking about python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter as you go, passing a tuple of the extensions you want to keep and filtering those with any to remove any files with matching extensions that don't contain any substring from your list of excluded substrings.

```
exc = [LIST OF EXCLUDED SUFFIXES]

import os
for f in os.listdir("path"):
    if f.endswith((".mp4",".mp3",".avi")) and not any(e in f for e in exc):
```

You only need a single pass over the directory content without any need to build a list first.

If you want to replace the forbidden substrings and not just exclude you can use re.sub:

```
import os
import re
r = re.compile(r"|".join([e for e in exc]))
for f in os.listdir("path"):
    if f.endswith((".mp4",".mp3",".avi")):
        f = r.sub("",f)
```

Comment: Now that is beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm! Now I need a clever way to strip out the offending suffix to clean up the filename. I guess I can use a similar trick again...

Comment: @DrChrisSmith, do you want to keep the file but remove the `_syndication` etc..?

Comment: Thank you. Vrey kind of you. This is a fantastic way to learn.

Comment: @DrChrisSmith, no prob, I edited the answer, let me know if that is what you meant

Comment: Lovely; very grateful. You've taught me a huge amount in under 30 minutes!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `any` with a generator expression to check all of the suffixes. You might also use a couple of temporary variables to aid readability.

```
included = fileExtension in filesAllowed
excluded = any(fileName.endswith(suffix) for suffix in suffixList)

if included and not excluded:
    ...
```

The expression inside `any` generates a series of `bool`s, and `any` checks if any of them are `True`.

Comment: Thank you; this is an amazing site. Within 10 minutes I have learned something new!